# Phonegap + Jquery / Populating a table / SQLlite or XML or JSON

Tags: jquery, xml, json, sqlite, cordova

I'm developing an application and have a question regarding populating tables, the data may change once per year, so I'd like to avoid network calls to a database.

So...

I'm using Jquery and Phonegap. I have lots of tables where I would consider coding statically, however, this data is likely to change once per year, so when I issue an update on the app I'd rather update one table then many different pages.  I am wondering what approach to take to ensure updating will be easy, and at least I can have a "Template" and only update where the information is stored rather than HTML. Please impose all your knowledge and if you could point me towards a tutorial on implementing that method.

V/r,
Kane

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Data that is retained for long periods of time is a good candidate for localStorage which is a widely supported capability.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

To store data in localStorage your code would look like this:

```
var s = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem("key", s);
```

Reversing the process looks like this:

```
var s = localStorage.getItem("key");
data = JSON.parse(s);
```

The data can be stored in any javascript object including arrays of objects and can be deeply nested.  The calls to retrieve the data this way are very fast.  If you need database-like support I suggest looking at lightweight libraries like underscore or lodash.

http://underscorejs.org/

http://lodash.com/

Solutions like WEBSQL or indexDB are still fragmented in their browser support.